# Jenkins - How to set authorization on project basis

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins I have two different projects and two users I want to authorize:

**User1** can only view, build, deploy **Project1**.

**User2** can only view, build, deploy **Project2**.

I have installed role based plugin, but am unable to get it working. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried with the role based plugin? Please explain that in detail. Also please link the plugin so we know which one we're talking about.

Comment: @michaelbahr i have used this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin and in Manage and assign roles I can see any option to authorize on job/project basis.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I agree Project Based could solve your problem but it would create headache on administrator if going forward you have 100 users.
Then For each user you have to give permissions,which will be a lot of effort and for those who are facing issues with  Role based plugin.
Here is the solution:-

Step 1:- click on  Global configuration under Manage Jenkins.

Step 2:- click on radio button "Role-Based Strategy" and save.

Step 3:- Go to Manage and Assign Roles under Manage Jenkins.

Step 4:- select Manage Roles.

Step 5:- You will see somewhat similar image as

[image: manage role]

Step 6:- Now add a global role part from admin under "role to add" option and grant Read Permission only.Shown in Blue color

For eg:- Employee in this case

Step 7:- For the above question and below example some assumptions

```
Test = Project1
check = Project2
```

Under Project roles:-

```
 Role to add:-developer

 Pattern:-Test
```

This means developer will be able to view only Project "Test".

Pattern is basically your project name.You can use regular expressions also here. For eg:- 
Pattern:- Tes*
then all projects beginning with Tes will have role as developer.

Similarly Add role as tester and Pattern as check,shown under black box,Tester will be able to view only Project "check"

Step 8:- Give the respective permissions view,build etc by check boxes and click on save.

Step 9:- Now go back to Manage Roles and select assign role and you will find something similar to this.

[image: assign role]

Step 10:- Under Global role add user1 and user2 and check box on to Employee as their role as shown in in the image above in black box.

[NOTE]Every New User/Group has to be added here and given the role of employee or admin.

Step 11:- Under Project Role,

Add user1 and user2 and assign them tester and developer role.
As shown in green color.

Click on save.

[NOTE]

```
Developer will be able to view only Project "Test"
tester will be able to view only  Project "check"
```

Comment: Thanks @Triangle.It's really very useful for me.

Comment: there are user groups for 100-s of users.

Comment: Yes, there may or may NOT exist user groups. Leave 100 even if you take 10 new user for each Project1 and Project2 in the above question  , Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin it would be time consuming for the Admin because the roles are already mentioned in the question which was a one time job at the starting.

Answer (score 9):

[Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Authorization+Strategy+Plugin) is the best option for your case. Very flexible configuration - both global and per project. You'll want to check in the 'Enable project-based security' option in project configuration ( the check box is close to the top of the job's config page ) and then add users/groups for which you want to configure the access permissions. After that use check boxes to set/remove permissions.

Comment: Good plugin choice, but there is no documentation :(

Comment: @Jan Lutenko ,hey I am not able to find 'Enable project-based security' ,are you talking about 'Enable securuty' check box that comes at top of Configure Global Security. I have checked it, but not able to authorize as per job basis.

Comment: @ranjitchoudhary where are you trying to configure this? I assume you are configuring in Jenkins security/system config. You wanted it for a project right? Check project config page - it's there.

Comment: @michaelbahr it is very self-explaining IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it, Go to Configure Global Security
In Security Realm : select Jenkins’ own user database and  Allow users to sign up.
then select Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy .
add users with authorization: Overall Read and Job Read.
Now save.

Now Create project and in Configuration select Enable project-based security.
and add that user to whom you want to provide authorization.
For details you can refer:
 http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jenkins-implementing-project-based-matrix-authorization-strategy/