# Jenkins - control who can trigger a build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there  a way we can control which user can click "Build Now" in Jenkins? Basically we dont want all the users who are logged in Jenkins to trigger a build.

Also is this possible project-wise?

I am relatively new in configuring Jenkins, though I have used Jenkins more as an end user and not an admin, so would really appreciate any helpful inputs. I tried using this : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security and this https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup, but for some reason its still allowing users to trigger a build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [RoleStrategyPlugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin)
This will be more helpful to manage large numbers of user using multiple projects.

The details to use and your doubt in the comment is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111825/jenkins-how-to-set-authorization-on-project-basis/32740116#32740116)

Comment: Thanks @Triangle, I was able to set this up, however, for some reason it looks like I cant use the regex facility for projects. For Example , if I have a project called HelloWorld, and if I apply the pattern like this Hel* , its somehow not working as expected. Could you please advise? This will solve my problem 100%.

Comment: You need to use the regex pattern like "Hel.*" without quotes and not Hel* 
You can see an example in RoleStrategy plugin under Manage Roles regarding the same.
Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Yup, I just fixed it. Thanks a lot for your help @Triangle

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Authorization+Strategy+Plugin), it offers matrix-based security authorization strategies, both global and per-project.

#### Global scope

> http://jenkins_server/configureSecurity/--> Authorization-->Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy

[image]

#### Project scope

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mainframer  - the Project scope does look promising, but here's my doubt - lets say we have two projects A and B and two users X and Y. Now , we want X to be able to do a "Build Now" only on project A and Y to be able to do a "Build Now" only on project B - I am not sure how would that be possible with the "Project Scope" approach above. Would this be possible with the standard Jenkins setup? Or are there any plugins that can help me do this? Could you please advise?