# Jenkins environment variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am a novice to Jenkins administration, trying to help a friend set up Jenkins for his startup.

I know there are plugins in Jenkins but not quite familiar on how to achieve his requirements.

He has a `spring` application which uses `dispatcher.xml` to reference `jdbc.properties` (one for each environment eg: `jdbc_dev`, `jdbc_test`, `jdbc_prod`.

How do I setup environment variables in Jenkins so the respective `jdbc.properties` is picked when the war file is built ?

Answer (score 1):

I think following plugins will help your friend a lot.

1) [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin):- To inject environment variables  depending on the requirements.

2) [Role strategy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) :- To manage authorization and permissions of various users. For eg: Admin,Tester,Developer,guest.

For more info on configuration on this plugin read this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111825/jenkins-how-to-set-authorization-on-project-basis/32740116#32740116)

3) [JobConfigHistory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin):- To revert changes if you screw anything.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

See [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build):

> Sometimes, it is useful/necessary to have your builds take several "parameters".
>
> ...
>
> The parameters are available as environment <s>parameters</s> variables. So e.g. a shell (*$FOO*, *%FOO%*) or Ant (*${env.FOO}*) can access these values.

[Corrections by me.]

See also the [Matrix Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin):

> A **multi-configuration project** is useful for instances where your builds will make many similar build steps, and you would otherwise be duplicating steps.