# Jenkins Role-based Auth plugin : Jobs sub directory regex match

Tags: regex, jenkins

I have created a jobs inside subdirectory called "projectv1.0/demo/dev1.0"

I tried to write a pattern match in "Role" tab to particular user. like

**projectv1.0/demo/dev1.0**

Its got failed. Is the subdirectory pattern match won't work on "Role-Based statergy Plugin.

Comment: Likely because the periods (`.`) are being interpreted as Regex wildcards. You could try escaping them using a backslash (`\\`) character.

Comment: How to escape the forwardslash in the above url?. Since I tried to change the project structure to " Project1/example/demo". Even this one also not working If I add pattern match "Project1/example/demo". 

It works when I simply add this rule "Project1.*". So I think, forwardslash has an issue, can you pls help me on how to resolve this one. thanks

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111825/jenkins-how-to-set-authorization-on-project-basis

Answer (score 7):

I also had the same issue. You need to use the following regexp: projectv1.0|projectv1.0/demo|projectv1.0/demo/dev1.0.*

more detailed info is available at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24767 (second comment)

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Jenkins [Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/) you can restrict access to only jobs under `projectv1.0/demo/dev1.0` folder adding a «**Item Role**» with the following **pattern**:

```sh
projectv1.0(/demo(/dev1.0(/.*)?)?)?
```