# Jenkins-How to set authorization on project basis using Role-based strategy plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

[Jenkins - How to set authorization on project basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111825/jenkins-how-to-set-authorization-on-project-basis/60173870?noredirect=1#comment106430905_60173870)

I have used Role-based strategy plugin and followed the steps in above link to setup the project roles.
I have given permissions to one project.
But i am able to see all the projects i currently have in my dashboard. To add to it, i am using active directory for the users. I am unable to figure out what the problem is, Could someone please help me sort this out

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Activate the Role-Based Strategy by using the standard Manage Jenkins > Manage Global Security screen: select role based stategy

then select the  criteria who can see jobs who can run build etc . add user or create roles assign  proper access level.

Comment: If i can access your master then can help you in minutes

Comment: i have selected the same in global security. i have attached some screeshots how i configured my roles.can you please have a look